# Cannot set property 'bootstrap' of undefined

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, popper.js

When i install bootstrap with npm, i ran folowing command:

- npm install bootstrap
- npm install popper.js --save

then i got the following directory tree:

-node_module
|__bootstrap
|__jquery
|__popper

and i use it:

```
<script type="module" src="<?php echo asset('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="module" src="<?php echo asset('node_modules/popper/dist/popper.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="module" src="<?php echo asset('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>">
```

but when i run it, it export an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'bootstrap'
>   of undefined
>
> ```
> at bootstrap.min.js:6
> at bootstrap.min.js:6
> ```

I dont know why, phease help!!
My packeage.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your package.json file please

Comment: i added it @KrzysztofRaciniewski

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove attribute `type="module"` and it will work - jQuery and Bootstrap in minified versions are just regular ES5 files

Comment: This works, however it's not possible to do with Vite. Import them as dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

And install popper.min.js from `node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd` directory to avoid error below:

```
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`
```

from what I see, you also have a bad location for `popper.min.js` file. This file is located in

```
node_modules/popper.js/dist
```

you have

```
node_modules/popper/dist
```

Working example:

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <title>Examplel Bootstrap page</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

   <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Never expand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample01" aria-controls="navbarsExample01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample01">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
   </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: this mean i must rename popper folder to popper.js folder, right?

Comment: Remove your node_modules directory and run `npm update` command. I have installed popper.js in 1.14.4 version :) Location for this package in node_modules directory: `/popper.js/dist`

Comment: And move `"jquery": "^3.3.1"` from devDependencies to "dependencies" :)

Comment: when i change src to node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js, it worked. thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help